# array implementation using c++ STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have tried these two cannot understand the difference

```
     vector<int >a(n) and vector<int >a[n]
```

Please someone explain.thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: implementing integer array using STL

Comment: For a fixed size array, try `const size_t ARRAY_SIZE = 42; int a[ARRAY_SIZE];`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews in C++11 and later, consiser using `std::array` instead: `std::array<int, ARRAY_SIZE> a;`

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer to your question is:

- `vector<int >a(n)` is a single `vector<int>` object with an initial size of `n` elements.
- `vector<int >a[n]` is a fixed array of `n` vector` objects that each have an initial size of 0.

Comment: and  `vector<int >a{n}` is a vector with single element of value `n`... true only for integral T and n.

Answer (score 2):

Your question gives no context at all so it is hard to formulate an answer.

First, there is a difference between a vector and an array. An array is a fixed-size container for elements of the same type, a vector is a resizeable container for elements of the same type. For arrays, you do not need the STL (although there is an array implementation in the STL).

Those are your options:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int my_plain_arr[ARRAY_SIZE]; // can never store more than 10 elements
std::vector<int> my_vector(ARRAY_SIZE); // 10 is the initial size, can grow
std::array<int, ARRAY_SIZE> my_stl_array; // can never store more than 10 elements
```

What your little code example showed was actually an array of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't call myself as an experienced c++ user, but I hope my answer will help.Mainly there are 3 ways of creating a one dimensional array

1. vector vectorName (or) vector vectorName(numberOfElements,StartingValue)
2. type ArrayName[size]
3. type* ArrayName

If you use the *first way*, you can do nice things such as "vectorName.push_back(element)",so it is a **dynamic** array.Basically you don't need to decide on the size **elements** you are going to need.

If you use the *second way* you create an array, but you have to decide on the maximum size of the array before using it.

if you use the *third* way, you are creating a pointer, to the very first element of the array,and you can allocate space on the heap with the **new** keyword,but you also need to decide how much space it is going to take.